# jquery animation scrolling whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to scroll and snap to various sections on the page. It works fine in the beginning but then animation plays with quite a lot of delays. The animations are also jittery and seem to happen at random intervals. Please help!

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

let sections = $(".scroll-dest");
let lastSt = 0;
let running = false;

$(window).scroll(event => {
  if(!running) {
    running = true
  event.preventDefault();
  let current = null;

  sections.each((i, v) => {
    if ($(v).isInViewport()) current = i;
  });

  let st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (st > lastSt) {
    // console.log("down");
    console.log(current != sections.length - 1)
    if (current != sections.length - 1) {
      $("html").animate(
        {
          scrollTop: $(sections[current + 1]).offset().top
        },
        500
      );
    }
  } else {
    // console.log("up");
    if (current > 0) {
      $("html").animate(
        {
          scrollTop: $(sections[current - 1]).offset().top
        },
        500
      );
    }
  }
  lastSt = st;
  running = false
}
});
```

*Also*, the script is supposed to scroll to the section which is either before or after the current section. But it is scrolling the whole length of the page, which is not what i want.

Comment: Try using `.stop().animate({...` to clear the queue before adding the next animation to it. You may also want to consider debouncing the `scroll` event handler, as it can be a performance killer when performing complex functions within it.

Comment: Doing that makes the animations really slow, also how do i debounce in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use scroll event for this, try using the [Intersection Observer API (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this. It was created to solve problems like yours, to react when elements are getting visible or intersecting with each other in the viewport.

First you would define the options for the IO:

```
let options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}
```

After the options are defined you say which elements you want to observe:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-dest');
```

As a last step you have to define what happens once an element comes into view and bind it to the elements you defined:

```
const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {

    // when element's is in viewport,
    // do something with it!
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      animate(entry.target);
      // remove observer after animation (if it is no longer needed). 
      // remove this line if you want to continue observing this element.
      observer.unobserve(entry.target); 
    }
  });
});
elements.forEach((element) => intersectionObserver.observe(element));
```

If you need to support older browsers than use this (official) [polyfill from w3c](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill), it recreates intersection observer with listening to scroll events. So it will still be slower on older browsers, nothing you can do about it here. But on newer ones there will be an increase in performance.

You can also think about using [window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) instead of jQuery animate to get better performance.